# Recreating Vertical Tab using only CSS

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

Can anyone help identify if the Vertical Tabs built on this page:
http://www.google.ca/doubleclick/insights/

Is it pure CSS or does it use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The classes assigned to the content `div`s are being changed as the tab selection is changed. That indicates to me that this is using JavaScript.